# Adding elements of list to list not working

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a list which contains lists,

`testList = [[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], ...]`

What I want to do is that add the list in groups of `n`, so if n is 2, the first two lists will be added together and the second two lists will be added together, it will be like `[1, 0, 1] + [1, 1, 1] = [2, 1, 2]`.

I tried the following code,

```
group_len = 3
sumResultList = [[sum(x) for x in zip(*testList)] for group in [testList[i:i+group_len] for i in range(0, len(testList), group_len)]]
```

But the above code does not work, how do I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
l = [[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1],
     [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1],
     [1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1],
     [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
n = 2
print [[sum(x) for x in zip(*l[a:a+n])] for a in range(0,len(l),n)]
```

Output:

```
[[2, 1, 2], [1, 0, 1], [2, 1, 2], [2, 2, 2]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that was what I was looking for, I made mine too complicated!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
testList = [[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [2,3,4], [2,3,4], [2,3,4]]

group_len = 2
res = [list(map(sum, zip(*testList[k:k+group_len]))) for k in range(0, len(testList), group_len)]
print(res)
```

output:

```
[[2, 1, 2], [2, 3, 4], [4, 6, 8]]
```